# If $f(x)=\tan^2\left(\dfrac{\pi x}{n^2-5n+8}\right)+\cot(\left(n+m)\pi x\right),\;(n\in N, m\in Q)$ is a periodic function with fundamental Period $2$

Tags: calculus, functions, gcd-and-lcm, periodic-functions

> If $f(x)=\tan^2\left(\dfrac{\pi x}{n^2-5n+8}\right)+\cot(\left(n+m)\pi x\right),\;(n\in N, m\in Q)$ is a periodic function with its fundamental period as $2$. Then find interval in which $m$ cannot belong to

(a) $(-\infty,-2)\cup (-1, \infty)$

(b) $(-\infty,-3)\cup (-2, \infty)$

(c) $(-3,-2)\cup(-2,-1)$

(d) $\left(-3,-\dfrac{5}{2}\right)\cup\left(-\dfrac{5}{2},-2\right)$

**My Approach:**

Period of $\tan^2\left(\dfrac{\pi x}{n^2-5n+8}\right)$ is $n^2-5n+8$ and Period of $\cot(\left(n+m)\pi x\right)$ is $\dfrac{1}{(m+n)}$

Period of overall function will be LCM of $n^2-5n+8$ and $\dfrac{1}{(m+n)}$

Let $m=\frac{p}{q}$ where $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $p,q \in I$

$\text{LCM}\left(n^2-5n+8,\dfrac{1}{\frac{p}{q}+n}\right)$

$\implies \text{LCM}\left(n^2-5n+8,\dfrac{q}{p+nq}\right)$
$\implies \dfrac{\text{LCM}(n^2-5n+8,q)}{\text{HCF}(1,np+q)}=\text{LCM}\left(n^2-5n+8,q\right)$

So we want $\text{LCM}\left(n^2-5n+8,q\right)=2$

**Now I don 't Know how to proceed further and How to find interval of $m$**

**Note:$\text{LCM}\left(\dfrac{x}{y},\dfrac{r}{t}\right)=\dfrac{\text{LCM}(x,r)}{\text{HCF}(y,t)}$ and $\text{HCF}\left(\dfrac{x}{y},\dfrac{r}{t}\right)=\dfrac{\text{HCF}(x,r)}{\text{LCM}(y,t)}$**

Comment: Either there is typo, or you have written period of cot incorrectly

Comment: @aarbee Fixed, Thanks.

Comment: Period of cot(m+n)x is $\frac{\pi}{m+n}$. Or maybe you have cot(m+n)$\pi$x in mind?

Comment: @aarbee Thanks, Fixed again

Comment: If $n=1, n^2-5n+8=4$

If $n=2, n^2-5n+8=2$

If $n=3, n^2-5n+8=2$

If $n=4, n^2-5n+8=4$

If LCM is $2$ then $n^2-5n+8$ can't be more than $2$.

Also, $q$ can't be more than $2$ either.

Comment: Also, is any information given about $x$? Domain? Because if $x=1$ then $n^2-5n+8$ can't be $2$ either as $\tan$ won't be defined there. In that case, $q$ should be $2$

Comment: @aarbee no information about $x$ is given. I've added options.